# Using clipper2lib to offset a path in only one direction

Tags: c#, vector-graphics, clipperlib

I am using the c# implementation of clipper2lib in Unity to offset an open path:[image]

I want it to offset only in one direction, as in this image I edited in gimp:

[image]

Ideally the first and last points in the offsetted path would land at right angles to the first and last line segments as in the illustration.

Note that while the source curve in the image is simple, the geometry of that curve at times might be complex and self intersecting, a scenario which the clipper library handles nicely. So simply translating the vertices along their normals is probably not going to work.

I don't see a way to to this with Clipper out of the box. Can it be done with Clipper or a different approach entirely?